# LoadRunner Warning: The string 'SomeString' with parameter delimiters is not a parameter

Tags: loadrunner

I am saving a parameter with the following C/LR code:

```
web_reg_save_param("Number",
 "LB=myleftboundry/",
 "RB=/myrioghtboundry",
 LAST);

lr_output_message("%s", lr_eval_string("my number: {Number}"));
```

But when running the script, I get some wired things in the log:

```
Action.c(66): Registering web_reg_save_param was successful      [MsgId: MMSG-26390]
Action.c(67): Warning: The string 'Number' with parameter delimiters is not a parameter.
Action.c(67): Number: {Number}
Action.c(69): Notify: Transaction "trans1" started.
Action.c(73): Notify: Saving Parameter "Number = 4588".
```

Anybody knows what I am doing wrong here?

Maybe it has to do with the building of my output statement?

Cheers

Magnus

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a solution to this in that for this to work another action function must be performed to perform `web_reg_save_param`.
Therefore I will put in the `web_reg_save_param` initailly in the script.

Answer (score 0):

I realize that my response here is a bit slow but I ran into this issue and by finding this post it pointed me into the right direction so I thought I'd place my solution to the issue here for others to read.

Simply change your web_reg_save_param to web_reg_save_param_ex.  That will resolve your issue.